# Tapestry `EntityManager` vs `EntityManagerManager`

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, tapestry, hibernate-entitymanager

In Tapestry there are (mainly) two ways to obtain an `EntityManager` instance:

1. By injecting the `EntityManager` directly:

   ```
   @Inject
   @PersistenceContext(unitName = MyPersistenceUnit)
   private EntityManager entityManager;
   ```
2. By using the `EntityManagerManager` (which is also injected):

   ```
   EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerManager.getEntityManager(MyPersistenceUnit);
   ```

The `EntityManagerManager` states in its javadoc that it manages one `EntityManager` per thread:

> Manages `EntityManager`s for the current thread. An
> `EntityManager` is created as needed and closed at the end
> of each request.
>
> The implementation of this service is per-thread.

Does this also apply for injecting the `EntityManager` directly? So for example, if I start a transaction in one thread, like that:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
```

will the transaction of the `EntityManager` in another thread be inactive - i.e. will `entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()` be false for other threads, where the `EntityManager` also was injected?

---

More generally I am curious about what *should* be used. What are the differences / advantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are equal, you can use any with same guarantees:
`EntityManager` is always a per-thread instance, nothing is shared between threads. Each `EntityManager` is discarded/closed at the end of each request (when `PerthreadManager#cleanup()` method is called).

`EntityManagerManager` is used as a source in `EntityManagerObjectProvider` which produces instances of `EntityManager` so that you could simply write `@Inject EntityManager` instead of obtaining it from the manager explicitly.